# Thymeleaf: How to work with a AbstractIterationElementProcessor class

Tags: spring, iteration, spring-boot, thymeleaf, processor

Anyone already get to work with a AbstractIterationElementProcessor derived class in a spring project which uses Thymeleaf? I am trying use this to implement this kind of tag:

```
<form:form ...>
    ...
</form:form>
```

The element is iterated based on a List which should be generated inside the processor class, based on the array with the list of field of the class from model class passed to the view (named `command`).

In each iteration, one element of the list is processed by a switch-like structure inside the tag and a inner element is chosen (`form:input`, `form:select`, etc).

Right now, I have this code:

```
public class FormProcessor extends AbstractIterationElementProcessor {

  public FormProcessor() {
    super("form");
  }

  @Override
  public void processClonedHostIterationElement(Arguments arguments, Element iteratedChild) {
    //
  }

  @Override
  public String getIteratedElementName(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
    return "form";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean removeHostIterationElement(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public AbstractIterationElementProcessor.IterationSpec getIterationSpec(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getPrecedence() {
    return 1000;
  }

}
```

But I am have some trouble to understand what implement in each method. Anyone can give a hint on how to do that?